# How to include an applet from a web page in a different directory?

Tags: java, html, applet

I'm trying to use the jZebra printing applet and am not sure how to use it from pages in different directories. The sample page has the following code:

```html
<applet 
    id="qz"
    name="QZ Print Plugin"
    code="qz.PrintApplet.class"
    width="55"
    height="55">
    <param name="jnlp_href" value="qz-print_jnlp.jnlp">
    <param name="cache_option" value="plugin">
    <param name="disable_logging" value="false">
</applet>
```

If the applet (qz-print.jar) and another file (qz-print_jnlp.jnlp) are in the same directory as the page with that code, then it works fine. However, I don't know what to change to get it to work if the web page is in a different directory. It seems like this is a trivial question, but I've been searching and haven't been able to find the answer.

How should I modify the above code to get the applet in the web page when it's in a different directory?

Answer (score 2):

The tag you are using:

```
<param name="jnlp_href" value="qz-print_jnlp.jnlp">
```

Is the equivalent of this: (notice the "./"):

```
<param name="jnlp_href" value="./qz-print_jnlp.jnlp">
```

Java uses absolute or relative paths, just as an image tag would `<img src="./foo.png />`

So, if you've placed your applet in one folder called "dist" (i.e. `http://mysite/dist/qz-print.jar`) but your page was located in another folder called "web"(i.e. `http://mysite/web/mypage.html`) then you would have to change your relative applet tag to this:

```
<param name="jnlp_href" value="../dist/qz-print_jnlp.jnlp">
```

Or optimally, change the tag to be absolute path to the jnlp:

```
<param name="jnlp_href" value="/dist/qz-print_jnlp.jnlp">
```

Additionally, as qz finds better ways to load these tags, we put them in the sample.html.  I would recommend you use the latest version from [here](http://www.qzindustries.com/download).

At the time of writing this, the best way to use the tags is this way:

`<applet id="qz" archive="./qz-print.jar" name="QZ Print Plugin" code="qz.PrintApplet.class" width="55" height="55">
    <param name="jnlp_href" value="qz-print_jnlp.jnlp">
    <param name="cache_option" value="plugin">
    <param name="disable_logging" value="false">
    <param name="initial_focus" value="false">
    <param name="separate_jvm" value="true">
</applet><br />`

Note that the archive tag should be updated as well as the jnlp tag.

The three changes from the sample you are using to the sample I've provided above are:

1. Initial focus stealing prevention for jQuery focus() events
2. The `archive=` tag for compatibility with certain versions of Safari.
3. The `separate_jvm` tag is used to load a new instance of the Java Framework on page load, which seems to resolve some sporadic loading issues with Java 8.

Finally, if you have clients that still run Java 6, I would advise you use `deployQZ();` from sample.html instead, which does Java client version detection using Oracle's `deployJava.js` script.

-Tres